# Excel Protection: How to control Excel Access only at Office Premise with MS Office licence check

Tags: excel

I was asked by one of the client that, they want to restrict the Excel work book within the office. ie if employees are using it with their personal laptops, it should not be accessible.

I am just wondering whether we can do some level of locking with Excel Licence owner? ie. if company procures the microsoft office licence for its employees , with that licence only, it should be accessible.

Any help on this ( or alternate solution) is appreciated

Comment: So how did you manage to check for valid licences?

Comment: The feature is available in Office 365 Enterprise Edition.  A weaker version can be coded into the startup code: does it need to be secure, or only indicative?